# angular: how do I make a dependent required field country->state?

Tags: angularjs

I have a field country. Some countries in the list like the US or Canada are divided into states. When such countries are selected, a second select appears and is required.

HTML:

```
<label>Country*</label>
<select name="country" class="gu3" ng-model="companyCriteria.country" ng-options="country.label for country in countries" required=""></select>

<div class="row" ng-show="stateAvailable">
  <label>Province*</label>
  <select name="state" class="gu3" ng-model="companyCriteria.state" required="">
    <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.code}}">{{state.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('CompanyController', function ( $scope, companies , Countries, States ... ) {
    //...

    $scope.countries = Countries;
    $scope.states = [];
    $scope.stateAvailable = false;

    $scope.$watch( 'companyCriteria.country', function( after, before ) {
        if ( searchCompanyCriteria.country && searchCompanyCriteria.country.div ) {
            $scope.states = States.get( after.code );
            $scope.stateAvailable = true;
        } else {
            $scope.states = [];
            $scope.stateAvailable = false;
        }
    } );

    $scope.search = function () {
        if ( !$scope.companyForm.$valid ) return; //Returns when states are hidden
        //Do search ...
    };
```

the problem is that $scope.companyForm.$valid is false when the state select is hidden. I'm not sure how to proceed to code it in an angular and elegant way (without having to hack with the dom the jquery way).

Note: Angular v1.2.0-rc.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ng-show` use [`ng-if`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf) (assuming you're using angular 1.1.5 or higher):

```html
<div class="row" ng-if="stateAvailable">
  <label>Province*</label>
  <select name="state" class="gu3" ng-model="companyCriteria.state" required>
    <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.code}}">{{state.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Or, just use [`ng-required`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput):

```html
<select name="state" ng-model="companyCriteria.state" ng-required="stateAvailable">
  <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.code}}">{{state.label}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: OR both :) if you don't want to show until the country is selected.

Comment: both the solutions work, thanks! One detail however: the browser behaviour with the `required` attribute doesn't work on the "state" select. It works with the country select (the bubble shows in chrome and firefox put a red outline)

Comment: @BiAiB if you are using angular forms you may need to attach `novalidate` attribute to the `form` tag (or `ng-form`).  This will turn off the html5 validation that is causing the red outline.

Comment: @DavinTryon I want the opposite, I want the red outline to show on all the required fields. But only the country is given the validation mark. Both in chrome and firefox. I tried with required, ng-required or required="required" on the state field but none work.

Comment: @DavinTryon but if I can't get around this strange behaviour, I'll follow your suggestion and turn off html5 validation

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-required` to resolve an angular expression and set the field to required:

```
<label>Country*</label>
<select name="country" class="gu3" ng-model="companyCriteria.country" ng-options="country.label for country in countries" required=""></select>

<div class="row" ng-show="stateAvailable">
  <label>Province*</label>
  <select name="state" class="gu3" ng-model="companyCriteria.state" ng-required="companyCriteria.country">
    <option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.code}}">{{state.label}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This will only require the state, if the country has been set with a value.  However, you can put in any scoped expression here (so if you want to call a controller function returning a boolean, that would work as well).

The documentation for `ng-required` is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput).

Comment: Thanks, your solution works but I validated Stewie's answer cause he provided another a supplementary way of achieving it.